# Image not showing in android studio emulator

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-layout

i don't know  what is the problem with my android studio i am trying to add an image from image view ..it is showing in design tab but not in emulator ...i am a newbie ..please help me fix it ..thanks[Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eanyp.jpg)

i tried fixing it by changing the attributes but didnt work ..

Comment: Try getting something else to show up there. Maybe there is something covering up that area.

Comment: You may be using `tools namespace` that enable design-time features which is making the ImageView visible on the design layout but not on the emulator. Please edit your question and paste your XML code.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a sample_image to an imageView. To set an image, give it a real source.

```
android:src="@drawable/any_image"
```

give source of an image `drawable`

Comment: It works, i donno why on course its 'tools'

Answer (score 0):

Download any jpg or png image from google and paste that image in drawable folder than add this line in to you imageview widget -> android:src="@drawable/TestImage"

like this->

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/TestImage">
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.
On 'Split View' everything works fine, but on emulator or phisical phone dont.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context=".questions">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_question"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text="Do jakiego kraju należy ta flaga?"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="Quiz Image"
        tools:src ="@drawable/germ"
        />
```

Comment: The question is related to emulator, if you believe that it is not working then this cannot be the response to this question

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:...` instead of `tools:...`.
It might fix the issue.

`tools:src ="@drawable/germ"` means that the image will be showing **Only** in Android Studio (aka. the Editor),

`android:src ="@drawable/germ"` means that the image will be showing in Android Studio and the Device (aka. the Emulator or the real Physical device/phone).

This applies to many attributes other than `src`.